# Java programme witch should calculate the amount of donations received

Tags: java, while-loop, output

We assume that the cakes baked in Part 1 and other dishes are distributed to a group of people in return for voluntary donations. The programme should calculate the amount of donations received and, based on the production costs, output whether the donations generated a profit or a loss. The production costs for the cakes must be entered.

Firstly, the production costs (= Kosten) incurred for baking (as a decimal number) and the number of people donating (= Anzahl der Abnhemer) should be entered. Then enter the amount of the donation (=Spendenanzhal) per person (as a decimal).

As soon as the current donation amount is at least as high as the costs based on the last donation entered, a message should be displayed (see example). There may be further donations after this. If no profit is made (i.e. the costs exceed the total donations), the programme should display "Loss" at the end.

Make sure that the formatting corresponds exactly to the examples.

Example:

```
? Costs: 5.20
? Number of customers: 5
? Donation: 2.50
? Donation: 0.80
? Donation: 2.00
--- Profit zone ---
? Donation: 0.50
? Donation: 1.00
Total donations: 6.8
Example:

? Cost: 4.80
? Number of recipients: 3
? Donation: 0.5
? Donation: 1
? Donation: 0.20
Total donations: 1.7
Loss
```

My current code is:

```
package einfprog;

    public class Bsp02 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO: Implement.
       // Teil 2

        SavitchIn in = new SavitchIn();//Teil 2
        
        System.out.print("? Kosten: ");
        double kosten = in.readDouble();

        System.out.print("? Anzahl der Abnehmer: ");
        int anzahlAbnehmer = in.readInt();

        // Gesamtspenden und Anzahl der Spenden
        double gesamtspenden = in.readInt();
        int spendenAnzahl = in.readInt();

        boolean gewinnZoneErreicht = false;

        // Eingabe der Spenden pro Person
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("? Spende: ");
            double spende = in.readDouble();
            
            gesamtspenden += spende;

            if (!gewinnZoneErreicht && gesamtspenden >= kosten) {
                gewinnZoneErreicht = true;
                System.out.println("--- Gewinnzone ---");
            }
            // Wenn alle Personen gespendet haben
            if (spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer) {
                break;
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Gesamtspenden: " + gesamtspenden);

        // Prüfen, ob Gewinn oder Verlust erzielt wurde
        if (gesamtspenden >= kosten) {
            
        } else {
            System.out.println("Verlust");
        }
    }
}
```

The programme is tested by a test (I don't know exactly what it asks for). At the moment I get an output error, which I think is due to the while loop.

> donateNumber is 0 and always remains 0. Therefore, the condition of the if statement donateNumber == numberofpurchasers will never result in true (if numberofpurchasers != 0)
> The variable number of donations is currently not being increased - but I could include a
> `spendenAnzahl++;`
> for this (in the while-loop)?

However, I can't get this to work without another output error or time out - could someone illustrate how I can solve this problem?

Many thanks for help in advance!

Comment: You need to design your program to match the requirements you were given: **1** Prompt user for cost.  **2** Have user enter cost.  **3** Prompt user for number of donors. **4** have user enter number of donors.  **5** Start a loop, which will iterate one time for each donor (number entered in step 4).  At each iteration, **5.1** prompt user for amount of donation. **5.2** Have user enter amount of donation.

Comment: Always run and test your code yourself before turning it in or submitting it. If you were given examples, use those examples in your testing. Create additional examples. Check if the results are what was expected, and match requirements.

Comment: You have a `while (true)` loop. To prevent your program from "infinite loop", a `break`   needs to be executed within the loop. The only `break` in the loop is conditional: `if (spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer) { break; }`.  Therefore, the loop will exit when, and only when `(spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer)` is true. But, nothing in the loop will change either of those values. So, the loop will either iterate one time or "forever". Which will be the case depends on whether they were equal or unequal before the loop started. (Ignored the possibility of having `return` in the loop. N/A here.)

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer:
Thank you - then i have already named the problem correctly in my post - but i still don't understand how to solve it. (spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer) must still be given according to the examples?
The code is not tested by me, but by a programme in which some test case is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all your variables actually relate to something. I'm not a big fan of `while (true) {`. Since you have already added a loop break mechanism within the     `while` loop block using

```
if (spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer) { break; }
```

why not use that concept as the condition for your `while` loop instead of just `true` except, use variables you have already in play and phrased a little
different, something similar to:

```
while (donationCount < numberOfCustomers) {
```

then within the `while` loop block, at the very beginning, have `donationCount++;`. Now you can get rid of that `if (spendenAnzahl == anzahlAbnehmer) { break; }`.

Putting this into practice would look something like this (be sure to read the comments in code):

```
// Open a Keyboard input stream:
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

// Get the Target Cost from User:
System.out.print("Required Target Cost? -> $");
double cost = in.nextDouble();

// Get the number of Customers that will be donating:
System.out.print("Number of Customers?  -> ");
int numberOfCustomers = in.nextInt();

// Total donations and number of donations
double totalDonated = 0.0d;         // Will hold the total sum of donations acquired.
int donationCount = 0;              // Counter for number of donations processed.
boolean profitZoneReached = false;  // Flag to indicate when in a donations profit state.

/* Enter donations per person. Iterate through 
   each Customer that will be donating.     */
while (donationCount < numberOfCustomers) {
    donationCount++;
    System.out.print("Customer Donation #" + (donationCount) + "? -> $");
    double donation = in.nextDouble();
    totalDonated += donation;  // Add the current donation to `totalDonated`:

    /* If the profitZoneReached flag is false and the 
       total donated amount has surpassed or equals the 
       Cost then set the profitZoneReached flag to true
       and display "--- Profit Zone ---".  */
    if (!profitZoneReached && totalDonated >= cost) {
        profitZoneReached = true;
        System.out.println("--- Profit Zone ---");
    }
}

// Indicate the sum of donations formatted to two decimal places):
System.out.println("Total donations:      -> $" + String.format("%.02f", totalDonated));

/* Check whether Target, Profit, or Loss was achieved:
   All displayed values are formatted to two decimal 
   places.        */
if (totalDonated == cost) {
    System.out.println("On Cost Target of     -> $" + String.format("%.02f", cost) + " :)");
}
else if (totalDonated > cost) {
    System.out.println("At a Profit of        -> $" + 
            String.format("%.02f", (totalDonated - cost)) + " :D");
}
else {
    System.out.println("At a Loss of          -> $" + String.format("%.02f", (cost - totalDonated)) + " :(");
}
```

Comment: @DevilsHand: Thank you very much for your factual explanation of my mistake - I was able to solve the problem :).